# Media Source - is it possible to have buffer that don't start with a key frame?

Tags: html, buffer, media-source

Using the media source extension, is it possible to do buffering in a way that buffers don't start with a key frame, but with a normal frame?

For instance, is it possible to buffer the video frame by frame? (Not saying that would be very smart to do!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but obviously you won't be able to see video until you feed it with a key frame.

Having said that, there is currently a limitation in Chrome causing failure to play video if fragments don't start with a key frame.
see here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=229412

Comment: @Guig fortunately and coincidentally, it was fixed yesterday. The fix should be in version 50 (probably ~2 month from now). You can see the details in the link I sent you.